# Who realized the finite fields $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ first? Gauss or Galois?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, ho.history-overview, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $n$ be a positive integer. The finite field $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is often called a Galois field and denoted by $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$ by researchers on coding theory.

On the other hand, by Ireland and Rosen's book *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* , Gauss first proved the existence of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, and this is essentially equivalent to the existence of the finite field $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

**Question.** Who realized $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ first? Galois or Gauss?

I wish to learn the real history.

Comment: It's hard to really answer, because as a 2022 person you take for granted the notion of field, of the "obvious" connection between irreducible polynomials and finite extensions. But at the time of Galois/Gauss the notion of field didn't exist. So there shouldn't be an obvious answer.

Comment: Echoing @YCor, it is a somewhat anachronistic question. That said, the first person to write down Galois' work on (what we today notice are) finite fields is probably Camille Jordan in his 1870 Traité. There, in Book 1, §3 (17-22), he talks about "Théorie de Galois", being how to construct finite fields (not what we call "Galois Theory" today). It is very recognisable: take $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$, prove that there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over it, and do some basic algebra. So Jordan would likely have answered: "Galois".

Comment: But to be clear, Jordan did NOT suddenly say: "and now we have constructed an algebraic structure that is a set with two binary operations, satisfying axioms A, B, C, ...". He talks about "the complex numbers formed by adjoining an imaginary to the integers". The axiomatisation of finite fields would not really be until closer to the turn of the century, particularly by E. H. Moore and L. E. Dickson. It was Moore who originated the phrase "Galois field" for these objects, and this was only in 1893.

Comment: Agreeing with other comments, essentially about the anachronism of the framing of the question: Gauss could do and did many things that we far-more-easily understand by this year in terms our "standard abstractions". But he did not operate in such a world. Galois' conception of general finite fields as "things-in-themselves" was amazing on many levels in that context.

Comment: Gauss's Disquisitiones Arithmeticae were planned to contain an 8th chapter on polynomials modulo $p$. A manuscript dated 1797 titled "Disquisitiones Generales de Congruentiis" was found in 1855 in Gauss's papers and published by Dedekind in 1863 in the second volume of Gauss's Werke. According to Frei (The Unpublished Section Eight, in Goldstein, Schappacher, Schwermer, ed., The Shaping of Arithmetic after Gauss's Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, Springer, 2007, 159-198), it was to contain a theory of cyclotomy modulo $p$, and Gauss used the analogy between algebraic equations and congruences.

Comment: Probably more suitable for [HSM Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)